# Populating a CheckBoxList with checked options programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I get the feeling I'm missing something really basic about the asp.net page life cycle here.

I have a CheckBoxList (Although the same thing happens with a ListBox)

```
    <asp:CheckBoxList runat="server" ID="cblCountriesAccessible" DataTextField="Text" />
```

I'm adding a bunch of ListItems to it

```
        var lbData = new List<ListItem>();
        lbData.Add(new ListItem("x", "", true));
        lbData.Add(new ListItem("y", "", false));
```

Then Binding them to the CheckBoxList

```
    cblCountriesAccessible.DataSource = lbData;
    cblCountriesAccessible.DataBind();
```

And every time the items in the list show up at unchecked (or unselected in a ListBox)
If I add the ListItems directly to the control in the markup, they show up just fine as selected or unselected.

```
    <asp:ListItem Text="x" Value="" Selected="True" />
```

What am I doing wrong in the code that selected doesn't carry through? I've tried binding CheckBoxes in with Checked set to true, and the same thing happens.

Edit: OK, I wasn't setting Selected correctly. I'm now using

```
        var lbData = new List<ListItem>();
        var l1 = new ListItem("yy", "", true) {Selected = true};
        var l2 = new ListItem("xx", "", true) {Selected = false};

        lbData.Add(l1);
        lbData.Add(l2);
```

And they're still not loading as checked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create [**ListItem**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem.aspx) change its `Selected` property and add in collection.

```
ListItem li1 = new ListItem("x", "", true);
ListItem li2 = new ListItem("x", "", true); 
li1.Selected = true; 
li2.Selected = true;
cblCountriesAccessible.Items.Add(li1);
cblCountriesAccessible.Items.Add(li2);
```

Comment: ListItem doesn't have a Checked Property, just Selected, which is set in the Constructor. I've tried making CheckBoxes instead of ListItems with Checked = true, but that didn't work either

Comment: Its Selected not Checked, Updated my code please have a look.

Comment: Selected is already set in third parameter in the constructor. Could you try this out and see if they show as selected if you run the code in the Page_Load? Maybe there's just something weird about my setup here.

Comment: According to the docs, the third parameter is actually specifying whether the item is enabled, not whether it's selected: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ec0w4405(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: D'oh, you're right, but even when I try li1.Selected = true, it still loads on the page as unchecked

Comment: Ah, I see, remove the data binding and it works. Just add the items straight to the connection. 
Still weird that the binding would drop the selection.

Answer (score 1):

`ListItem.Enabled` is not the same as `ListItem.Selected` . Per this MSDN page ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listitem.enabled.aspx )

Enabled simply determines if it COULD be selected. When creating an item with this overload, it does not select it.

Per this page ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxlist.aspx ) : "To determine the selected items in the CheckBoxList control, iterate through the Items collection and test the Selected property of each item in the collection."

I have done this in the past using LINQ by having my list of items pre-determined and then iterating through them.

Here's some un-tested code that should give you an idea. This is basically how I did this same thing with Win Forms, so your usage may be slightly different:

```
For each item in Items
    CheckedListBox.Items.Add(item.Name,Item.value,True)
Next

dim selectedItems as list(of Item) = items.where(function (x) x.selected = True)

for each item in CheckedListBox.items
    item.Selected = selectedItems.contains(item.Value)
next
```

Comment: Ok, that works. The Selected property seems to be dumped when you DataBind. If you cycle through the Items you just bound THEN set the Selected property it works. 
For extra brownie points could anyone explain why?

Comment: @Mikey, because the rendered HTML is an input list, which only has the Checked property to set it as "Selected". In otherwords the control has to bind to the data, build itself AND THEN it's exposed as a list of checkboxes. To get around this, use a Repeater instead.

Answer (score 0):

```
public string GetListItems()
{
    System.Collections.Generic.List<string> items = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string>();

    foreach (ListItem item in lstfunction.Items)
    {
        if (item.Selected)
        {
            items.Add(item.Value);
        }
    }

    return String.Join(", ", items.ToArray());
}
```